# Setting jax-ws property faultStackTraceEnabled and exceptionMessageCauseEnabled from java code when using CXF

Tags: jax-ws, cxf

To help troubleshoot a webservice, I would like to turn faultStackTraceEnabled and exceptionMessageCauseEnabled to true.

It appears to be an endpoint setting that can be defined in the configuration XML https://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-ws-configuration.html.  The only problem with that is that there is no configuration xml.  The client was created using CXF version 2.5.2 wsdl2java.  The configuration appears to be annotations only.

Tried some code to get the end point and set the properties, but it doesn't work.

```
        UserManagementService ss = new UserManagementService();
        UserManagementServiceV10 port = ss.getUserManagementServiceV10();  

        org.apache.cxf.endpoint.Client client =
                org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.getClient(port);
        org.apache.cxf.endpoint.Endpoint cxfEndpoint = client.getEndpoint();
        EndpointInfo endPointInfo = cxfEndpoint.getEndpointInfo();
        endPointInfo.setProperty("faultStackTraceEnabled", "true");
        endPointInfo.setProperty("exceptionMessageCauseEnabled", "true");
```

Answer (score 0):

Those setting are for server side only to tell the server to return the fault traces and causes back to the client.   They wouldn't have any effect on the client side.  I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks for the response Daniel.

This call fails.

GetRolesResponse getRolesResponse = port.getRoles(getRolesRequest,requestHeaderInfo,holder);

With this exception:

2012-03-14 15:28:43,862 [main] ERROR edu.wmich.d2l_ws.TestGetUser  - Thrown java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object

There is no stack trace and no error detail so I thought that it had to do with the properties.

This call:
GetRolesResponse getRolesResponse = port.getRoles(getRolesRequest);

Works fine, but I have to add a header.  That's why I opted for the call that has the requestHeaderInfo parameter.

Comment: I rebuilt the web service with axis 2.  Axis 2 throws a null pointer.  After debugging, it looks as though I'm getting a soap fault instead of the expected response.  That is probably why CXF is giving me an error too.   It's tricky to debug https web services.  The lack of a stack trace in CXF made it more difficult.  If there is an easier way to debug, please let me know.